# Calculating the sine of pi with php

Tags: php

I am trying to write a function to calculate the new x and y cooridinates after a rotation.
But for some reason it seems as though the sin function is not working as it should on a 180° angle:

```
$radians = deg2rad(180);
var_dump($radians);
$sin = sin($radians);
var_dump($sin);
```

Is there a workaround or something obvious I'm missing?

(The sin of pi should be 0).

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Comment: I get that. But is there no work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The math functions use floating points. Because of the computational nature of floats, they have a few [accuracy problems.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) The solution is to simply round your numbers:

```
$radians = deg2rad( 180 );
var_dump( $radians );

$sin = sin( $radians );
var_dump( round($sin, 3) );
```